# Multi-Occurence delete function in the linked list only deletes first instance of character

Tags: c

I am attempting to delete several occurrences of a word stored in a linked list. However, these words are stored by character in a single node instead of as a whole word in a list. For example, The pink flamingo is stored as:
T->h->e-> ->p->i->n->k-> ->f->l->a->m->i->n->g->o. Say the user wants to find pink. They have to loop through and delete each of these nodes.

I have attempted to create a loop which copies the contents of the linked list into a search function. I think copy this search function into another string. I am able to successfully delete the first occurrence of the desired character. However, I'm unable to do much else. I've attempted several times to push the node to the next node after deletion, but that also hasn't worked. It produced the same error.

```
void nodeDeletions(struct node** reference_to_headNode, struct node* deleteNode){

    if(*reference_to_headNode == NULL){
        return;
    }
    if(*reference_to_headNode == deleteNode){

        printf("Test A\n");
        *reference_to_headNode = deleteNode->nextNode;
    }
    if(deleteNode->nextNode != NULL){

        printf("Test B\n");
        deleteNode->nextNode->previousNode = deleteNode->previousNode;
    }
    if(deleteNode->previousNode != NULL){

        printf("Test C\n");
        deleteNode->previousNode->nextNode = deleteNode ->nextNode;
    }

    free(deleteNode);
}

void deleteWord(struct node** reference_to_headNode, char word_to_delete[]){

    struct node *tempNode;
    struct node *nextNode;

    int searchIndex = 0;
    int characterIndex = 0;
    const int arraySize = 101;
    const int arraySize2 = 202;

    char searchWordIndex[arraySize];
    char searchWordCopyIndex[arraySize2];

    if(*reference_to_headNode == NULL){
        return;
    }

    else {

        for (tempNode = *reference_to_headNode; tempNode != NULL; tempNode = tempNode->nextNode) {

            searchWordIndex[searchIndex] = tempNode->character;
            searchIndex++;

        }

        strcpy_s(searchWordCopyIndex, searchWordIndex);

        int length_of_searchIndex = strlen(searchWordCopyIndex);
        int length_of_deletionWord = strlen(word_to_delete);

        tempNode = *reference_to_headNode;

        for (searchIndex = 0; searchIndex < length_of_searchIndex; searchIndex++) {

            printf("Test 1\n");
            if(tempNode != NULL) {

                if(tempNode->character == word_to_delete[0]) {

                    for (characterIndex = 0; characterIndex < length_of_deletionWord; characterIndex++) {


                        printf("Test 2\n");
                        if (searchWordCopyIndex[searchIndex] == word_to_delete[characterIndex]) {


                            printf("Test 3\n");
                            if (tempNode->character == word_to_delete[characterIndex]) {

                                printf("Test 4\n");
                                printf("%c\n", tempNode->character);
                                printf("%c\n%c\n", word_to_delete[characterIndex], searchWordCopyIndex[searchIndex]);

                                nextNode = tempNode->nextNode;

                                nodeDeletions(reference_to_headNode, tempNode);

                                tempNode = nextNode;
                            }
                            else {
                                printf("Test 5\n");

                                tempNode = tempNode->nextNode;

                            }

                        }


                    }


                }

            }

            tempNode = tempNode->nextNode;

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phew! That's a lot of indented clode blocks. And a lot of auxiliary arrays and indices. And very long variable names. `:)`

Basically, you are dealing with three different types of iterating forwards through stuff, which are all present in your code:

- Traverse a character string:

  ```
  while (*s) {
      // do stuff with *s
      s++;
  }
  ```
- Traverse a linked list:

  ```
  while (p) {
      // do stuff with *p
      p = p->next;
  }
  ```
- Traverse a linked list via a reference to the source, so that you can modify it:

  ```
  while (*p) {
      // do stuff with **p
      p = &(*p)->next;;
  }
  ```

You only have to combine these three basic loops.

You can walk through the list with the third method (because you need to be able to update the head or next links when you delete). For each node you visit, compare the "tail" of that node with an auxiliary pointer `p` and the string `s` using the other two methods simultaneously. When the string matches, `*s == '\0'` and `p` points to the first node after the word. Delete all nodes by advancing the head until the head is `p`.

In other words:

- Traverse the list via `*head`.
- At each node:

  - set `p = *head` and `s` to the begining of the string;
  - traverse the list and the word while the letters match;
  - If `*s == '\0'`, there is a match. Now, `*head` points to the start of the word to delete in the list, `p` points to the first node after the word in the list, which may be `NULL`.
  - If there is a match, advance `*head` until `*head == p`, deleting the nodes as you go.

Or, in code:

```
void delete_word(struct node **head, const char *str)
{
    while (*head) {
        struct node *p = *head;
        const char *s = str;

        while (p && *s && p->c == *s) {
            p = p->next;
            s++;
        }

        if (*s == '\0') {
            while (*head != p) {
                struct node *del = *head;
                *head = (*head)->next;

                delete_node(del);
            }
        } else {    
            head = &(*head)->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is infinitely simpler code. I don't know why I made my function so complicated. I guess the concept behind my code was to check if the array values matched and to delete the values that matched. The concept was there, but the code was becoming far too complicated.

Comment: Could you explain this line to me: while (p && *s && p->c == *s) ? While nodeptr and strCopy and nodePtr points to character is equal to character in string? Thank you.

Comment: In English, that loop reads: While `p` points to a valid node and `s` points to a valid character and the characters both point to are the same, advance both `p` and `s`. After this loop terminates, either `p == NULL` or the characters differ (in which cases there's no match) or `*s == `'\0'` (in which case the node sequence starting from `*head` holds the same letters as the string).

Comment: Don't worry about complicate code; being able to simplify comes with experience. For example, you check whether the first letter of the string matches the current node before looping. That's sensible, but the loop will catch that case anyway, so you can save one level of indentation. I guess your problem was that you wanted to delete the nodes whie still checking, but you must know whether and where to delete before you can actually delete. My code with the two subsequent loops does that.